# Three.js Fog only working in one specific case

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have enabled fog for a scene in three.js. Also the materials
have the fog boolean enabled.

When i reload the page and quickly switch to another application (or another space on mac) and then go back to the site, the fog works properly.

If I don't do that, the fog is just not appearing.

Is that a common problem with webgl or something?

I'm using Three.js r71.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem is that the scene fog has to be enabled before adding objects to the scene, because enabling doesn't re-render the shaders.